# What happens to Adobe Air applications when Flash becomes unsupported in 2021?

Tags: flash, air, flex4

I understand browser-based Flash apps will become unusable at the end of the year when browsers drop support: https://blog.adobe.com/en/publish/2017/07/25/adobe-flash-update.html#gs.jasqm6

Extended support for Flash applications, including a new Flash runtime, is available through a license with Harman: https://services.harman.com/partners/adobe

My question: **what happens to existing Air applications with a Flash dependency** in 2021? Will they continue to technically function technically, but run unsupported?

More specifically, would it be technically feasible to port a browser-based Flex 4 application to run as a standalone desktop Air app?

Comment: Nothing is going to happen to **AIR**-based applications, desktop or mobile. The Fundamental Flash Flush Unavoidable Update (a.k.a. FFFUU) is only related to **browsers** discontinuing their support of Flash Plugin.

Answer (score 3):

As Adobe announced in [their blog post](https://blog.adobe.com/en/2019/05/30/the-future-of-adobe-air.html#gs.kuwxar) at the end of May 2019, HARMAN have taken on the platform support and feature development of the AIR software.

> HARMAN intends to continue supporting AIR on the existing platforms -
> Android, iOS, Windows, and macOS - and working with the existing IDEs,
> in order to make the transition from Adobe's versions of the SDK to
> HARMAN's version as seamless as possible. AIR will now be provided on
> a commercial basis, with a free version available for certain eligible
> individuals/companies, and then with a subscription to use the tools
> provided by the AIR SDK.